# Create new column and assign value to new column

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

i would like to seek help in assigning the filename value (eg. file1.txt) to a new col (eg. filename). However im stuck at the portion to create new column and assigning the value with the filename. No new column was seen when i export it as .csv. Appreciate if can advise whether my logic is wrong.

```
-raw text (no column names)-

file1.txt -> AL; 1A;
file1.txt -> BL; 2A;
file1.txt -> CL; 3A;

-sample file path - C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder\file1.txt-

-desired output (add filename col)-

name class filename
AL   1A    file1.txt
BL   2A    file2.txt
CL   3A    file3.txt
```

```
-current progress-

import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

src_path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder' #3 files total

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_path ,"*.txt")):
    filename = f #file1.txt
    files = [pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';', names = ['name', 'class'], index_col = False)]
    files_df = pd.DataFrame(files) #convert to df to add new column
    files_df['filename'] = f #assign value to new column

files_df = pd.concat(files_df) #concat all file data together
files_df.to_csv("df.csv")
```

```
---update---

#trying to include index value for each row's data.

#desired output
name class filename
AL   1A    file1_1.txt
AL   1A    file1_2.txt
BL   2A    file2_1.txt
BL   2A    file2_2.txt
CL   3A    file3_1.txt
CL   3A    file3_2.txt

import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

i = 0

src_path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder' #3 files total

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';', names=['name', 'class'], index_col=False
                       ).assign(filename=f)
           for i, f in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(src_path ,"*.txt"))), i+=1]
          ).to_csv("df.csv")
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` typically generates a single dataframe. Why are you putting it in a one-element list? (in the line `files = [pd.read_csv(...)]`) An example of your input format might make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I imagine your code should be changed to:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

src_path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder' #3 files total


all_dfs = []

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_path ,"*.txt")):
    tmp_df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';', names=['name', 'class'], index_col=False)
    all_dfs.append(tmp_df.assign(filename=f))

files_df = pd.concat(all_dfs) #concat all file data together
files_df.to_csv("df.csv")
```

As a "one-liner":

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

src_path = r'C:\Users\CL\Desktop\folder' #3 files total

pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=';', names=['name', 'class'], index_col=False
                       ).assign(filename=f)
           for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(src_path ,"*.txt"))]
          ).to_csv("df.csv")
```

Comment: wow.. thank you so much. i have much to learn that its possible to compress it to one-liner. thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that one-liner are not always the best. It can be more explicit to split the logic in several chunks. and conversely `temp_var = func(a) ; temp_var2 = func2(temp_var) ; ...` is not very informative. You have to find the right balance. ;)

Comment: sorry can i ask, i realize i need to include an index number as well to keep track of the different row numbers in each file. it should be stored together with filename (ie. row 1 - filename_1, row 2 - filename_2, etc). could you advise and see my edited post? it is facing syntax error. thank you